# How to add EF core migrations to .net core 2 class library?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I created a .net core 2 class library. and I created the entities and entities type configurations. I created the DbContext

```
public class EFDBContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

then I created a TemporaryDbContextFactory

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<EFDBContext>
{
    public EFDBContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EFDBContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Name=AppConnectionString",
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(EFDBContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new EFDBContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run Add-Migration but I got nothing. the migration is not created

So what am I missing here ??

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. Command executed but the migration is not created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're hitting issue [#10298](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10298). Add the following to your `*.csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```